# How to resolve Cannot read properties of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nestedArray')"
```

What is the solution to this? This is my beforeCreate functions:

```
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadCities").then((response) => {
      this.cities = response;
      this.sortingCities=this.cities.slice(0).sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.row - b.row || a.col-b.col;
      })
     
      this.sortingCities.map(item => {
        if (!this.nestedArray[item.row]) {
          this.nestedArray[item.row] = [];
        }
        this.nestedArray[item.row][item.col] = item;
      });
    });
```

My data property:

```
  data() {
    return {
      cities: [],
      selectedCity: null,
      sortingCities:[],
      nestedArray:[],
    };
  },
```

I use this property:

```
<img  :src="require(`../images/${this.nestedArray?.[row]?.[col].imageId}.png`)" alt="">
```

Comment: You don't need `this` in `template`.

Comment: @oguzcan Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @kissu I was not aware. I undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `beforeCreate` you should not expect any `data`, `methods` or `computed` to be available. This is [documented here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforecreate) (vue 3) and [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate) (vue 2).

Move the contents of `beforeCreated` into `mounted`.
If you have anything in `<template>` depending on the fetched data, give it an appropriate `v-if` (e.g: `v-if="nestedArray.length"`).

Answer (score 0):

***Root cause of the problem  :*** Issue is in accessing the `data` object properties inside `beforeCreate` life cycle hook. This life cycle hook called immediately after the instance has been initialized, before processing `data` option.

***Solution :*** You can put your logic inside `mounted()` hook instead of  beforeCreate as it is called after the instance has been mounted.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: []
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.message.push('beforeCreate hook called!'); // ❌
  },
  mounted() {
    this.message.push('mounted hook called!'); // ✅
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ message }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the vue data without vue is created? Strange, isn't it? Instead, you can access the data using *created* and after that lifeCycles. Here is a small sample for you.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
     nestedArrays: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.nestedArrays)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```